# comparing area of a square with area of rectangle

Tags: geometric-series

[image]

If we have a geometric sequence we have $a_1, a_1*r, a_2*r$

So $b=a_1*r$ and $c=a_2*r$

The square has area $b^2$ which is $(a_1*r)^2$ and the rectangle has area $ac = a_1*a_2*r$

I don't know which one is bigger or if this was even a correct way of interpreting the problem. Can someone please help.

Comment: $a_2=b=a_1r$. So, $c=a_2r=a_1r^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a$, $b$ and $c$ is in a geometric sequence.

$\dfrac{b}{a}=\dfrac{c}{b}$

So, $ac=b^2$.

Comment: ugh i am so dumb, thanks for the help.

Comment: i can accept your answer in 11 min, so i'll do it then